# I clearly see a positional argument defined, so why is it giving me this error?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to condense my file format. I've changed the headers to match my function. It's worked previously, but with this new file I'm getting a positional argument error.

```
input_fname = 'basic.xlsx'  # input filename
output_fname = 'basic-condensed.xlsx'  # output filename
basic_all = pd.read_excel(input_fname)

catalog_id_column = 'Product Number'
price_columns = 'List Price'
size_column = 'Size'

basic_all_condensed = condense_excel_multiprice(basic_all, price_columns, size_column)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_fname,
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        options={'strings_to_urls': False})

gbio_abs_condensed.to_excel(writer, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
writer.close()
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-146-614ba8c55380> in <module>
     22 
     23 
---> 24 basicbio_all_condensed = condense_excel_multiprice(basicbio_all, price_columns, size_column)
     25 
     26 writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_fname,

TypeError: condense_excel_multiprice() missing 1 required positional argument: 'size_column
```

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: sorry, forgot to include the error

Comment: Sorry, more questions - Where is condense_excel_multiprice defined?

Comment: That means there's one argument that you didn't specify. It doesn't mean that there's only one argument total to be specified

Comment: We would have to see the definition of `condense_excel_multiprice` to advise, you, but you'll likely find that it requires 4 parameters and you're supplying 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you have a variable called `size_column` doesn't mean it was passed in the same/correct position that your function's signature expected.

Take this example:

```py
def foo(x, y, ax=None):
    return x + y

y = 1
foo(y)
```

This generates the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-cf0d9fb1194f> in <module>
      3 
      4 y = 1
----> 5 foo(y)

TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

That's because I'm passing `y` as the first agrument, which my function refers to as `x`. Even though I passed `y`, I'm still missing one argument

Comment: Oh yea, you're absolutely right, someone added an additional argument I didn't notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error output is stating that there is 1 missing argument that is required by the function `condense_excel_multiprice`.

The function call has the local variables `basic_all, price_columns, size_column` but is asking for `size_column` which leads me to believe there is a required value missing before the `size_column` argument provided. Check that function definition for the arguments required to execute the function call.